# Prove $4(xy+yz+zx-xyz) \geqslant (x^2y+z)(y^2z+x)(z^2x+y)$ for $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> **Problem.** Let $x,y,z\ge 0: x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4.$ Prove that$$4(xy+yz+zx-xyz) \geqslant (x^2y+z)(y^2z+x)(z^2x+y).$$
> It was [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h587650_ineq_2)

The condition implies me set the substitution $$x=\frac{2a}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}};y=\frac{2b}{\sqrt{(a+b)(b+c)}};z=\frac{2c}{\sqrt{(c+b)(a+c)}}.$$
The rest is quite complicated. I think we can find a better ideas. Thank you very much.

Comment: $x=2-\frac{4bc}{(b + a)(c + a)}$ works. Should make $c{\le}a\frac{b+a}{b-a}$ if $a<b{\le}c$, or $c{\le}a\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ if $b<a{\le}c$, to ensure *x* non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**.

We use pqr method.

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.

The condition $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$ becomes
$$p^2 - 2q + r = 4. \tag{1}$$

From (1), we have
$$0 \le r \le 1, \quad 2 \le p \le 3, \quad q = \frac12 p^2 + \frac12 r - 2. \tag{2}$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &(x^2y + z)(y^2z + x)(z^2x + y)\\
 ={}&{x}^{3}{y}^{3}{z}^{3}+{x}^{4}y{z}^{2}+{x}^{2}{y}^{4}z+x{y}^{2}{z}^{4}+
 {x}^{3}{y}^{2}+{z}^{3}{x}^{2}+{y}^{3}{z}^{2}+xyz\\
 ={}& r^3 + r(xy^3 + yz^3 + zx^3) + (x^3y^2 + y^3z^2 + z^3x^2) + r\\
 ={}& (x^2y + y^2z + z^2x) (q - pr) +{p}^{2}qr-{p}^{2}r-2\,p{r}^{2}-{q}^{2}r+{r}^{3
 }+rq+r\\
 \le{}& \left(\frac{4}{27}p^3 - r\right) (q - pr) +{p}^{2}qr-{p}^{2}r-2\,p{r}^{2}-{q}^{2}r+{r}^{3
 }+rq+r \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we use $q - pr \ge \sqrt{3pr} - pr
\ge \sqrt{3p}\, r - pr \ge 0$ (using $q^2 \ge 3pr$ and $r \le 1$ and $p\le 3$),
and the [known inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825766/how-to-prove-this-inequality-a2b2c2-leq-3/3706748#3706748)
$x^2y + y^2z + z^2x \le \frac{4}{27}(x + y + z)^3 - xyz$.

It suffices to prove that
$$4(q - r) \ge \left(\frac{4}{27}p^3 - r\right) (q - pr) +{p}^{2}qr-{p}^{2}r-2\,p{r}^{2}-{q}^{2}r+{r}^{3
}+rq+r. \tag{4}$$

From (2) and (4), using $q = \frac12 p^2 + \frac12 r - 2$, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 g(p, r) &:= -81\,{r}^{3}+ \left( 108\,p-216 \right) {r}^{2}+ \left( -11\,{p}^{4}-8
 \,{p}^{3}+108\,{p}^{2}+108 \right) r\\
 &\qquad + 8(p-2)(3-p)(p+2)(p^2 + 3p + 9) \ge 0.\tag{5}
\end{align*}

From (2), using $q = \frac12 p^2 + \frac12 r - 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
 0 &\le (x - y)^2(y - z)^2(z - x)^2\\
 &= -4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2}\\
 &= \frac{p^2 + 4p + 2r + 4}{4}[-{r}^{2}+ \left( -2\,{p}^{2}+20\,p-40 \right) r-{p}^{4}+4\,{p}^{3}+4\,
 {p}^{2}-32\,p+32
 ]
\end{align*}
which results in
$$f(p, r) := -{r}^{2}+ \left( -2\,{p}^{2}+20\,p-40 \right) r-{p}^{4}+4\,{p}^{3}+4\,
{p}^{2}-32\,p+32 \ge 0. \tag{6}$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &g(p, r) - 81r \cdot f(p, r) \\
 ={}&
  \left( 162\,{p}^{2}-1512\,p+3024 \right) {r}^{2}+ \left( 70\,{p}^{4}-
 332\,{p}^{3}-216\,{p}^{2}+2592\,p-2484 \right) r\\
 &\qquad + 8(p-2)(3-p)(p+2)(p^2 + 3p + 9)\\
 ={}& 8( p-2)( 3-p ) ( p+2 ) 
 ( {p}^{2}+3\,p+9)  ( 1-r ) ^{2}\\
 &\qquad + ( -16\,{
  p}^{5}+70\,{p}^{4}-268\,{p}^{3}+216\,{p}^{2}+2592\,p-4212) r
 ( 1-r ) \\
 &\qquad + ( -8\,{p}^{5}+70\,{p}^{4}-300\,{p}^{3}+162
 \,{p}^{2}+1080\,p-324) {r}^{2}\\
 \ge{}& 0 \tag{7}
\end{align*}
where we use
$ -16\,{
 p}^{5}+70\,{p}^{4}-268\,{p}^{3}+216\,{p}^{2}+2592\,p-4212\ge 0$
and $-8\,{p}^{5}+70\,{p}^{4}-300\,{p}^{3}+162
\,{p}^{2}+1080\,p-324 \ge 0$ for all $2\le p \le 3$ (easy to prove),
and $0 \le r \le 1$.

From (5), (6) and (7), the desired result follows.

We are done.

Comment: It is a nice solution. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @TATAbox My proof is not nice. Hope to see nice proofs.

Comment: The problem is not easy at all. Your solution is possible with a little calculating work.

Comment: could you please take a look help me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743736/if-abbcca-1-prove-sqrt5a5b8ab-sqrt5c5b8cb-sqrt5a5c8ac-ge-3

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following will help.

Let $x=a-2$, $y=b-2$ and $z=c-2$, where $\{a,b,c\}\subset[2,4].$

Thus, the condition gives $$\sum_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)=abc$$ and we need to prove that
$$4\left(\sum_{cyc}\left(a-\tfrac{2abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\right)\left(b-\tfrac{2abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\right)\cdot\tfrac{abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}-\prod_{cyc}\left(a-\tfrac{2abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\right)\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(\left(a-\tfrac{2abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\right)^2\left(b-\tfrac{2abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\right)+\left(c-\tfrac{2abc}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)}\right)\cdot\tfrac{a^2b^2c^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)\right)^2}\right)$$ or
$$4a^4b^4c^4\left(\sum_{cyc}ab(2ab+2ac-a^2-b^2-c^2)(2ab+2bc-a^2-b^2-c^2)-\prod_{cyc}(2ab+2ac-a^2-b^2-c^2)\right)$$
$$\geq\prod_{cyc}\left((2ab+2ac-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2(2ab+2bc-a^2-b^2-c^2)+c^3b(2ac+2bc-a^2-b^2-c^2)\right),$$ which is $18$-th degree homogeneous polynomial inequality.

Also, the condition $\{a,b,c\}\subset[2,4]$ gives
$$a+b-c\geq2+2-4\geq0$$ and we can assume that $a=v+w$, $b=u+w$ and $c=u+v,$ where $u$, $v$ and $w$ are non-negatives.

Also, $$2ab+2ac-a^2-b^2-c^2=$$
$$=2(w^2+v^2+2(uv+uw+vw)-u^2-v^2-w^2-uv-uw-vw)=$$
$$=2(uv+uw+vw-u^2)\geq0,$$  $$uv+uw+vw-v^2\geq0$$ and
$$uv+uw+vw-w^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Your idea is out of my reach, @Michael Rozenberg. The substitution is nice. Did you check 18-th degree homogeneous polynomial inequality ?

Comment: @TATA box I have no software. To make it by hand it's very difficult. This substitution gives a possibility to make homogenization.